# Qgis2threejs wireframe mode displays diagonals (not just edges) of buildings

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs

I have exported an ESRI Shapefile of building polygons using Qgis2threejs in QGIS 2.18.14.

When attempting to view these buildings in wireframe mode it shows the edges of the buildings, as well as additional diagonals in purple.

[image]

How can I get it to only have the black edges?

Comment: did you get it to work?

Answer (score 3):

In short: you can't, not with the plugin itself.

Simple explanation: the `wireframe`represents the **mesh of *faces*** all geometries consist of, **not the outlines of geometries**. In *Three.js*, all *faces* are triangles by default (quad face support has been dropped in some earlier revision), thus the diagonals.

---

It is possible to render the hard edges of geometries by creating a `THREE.EdgeGeometry`, here from the `THREE.BoxBufferGeometry`, usually with a `THREE.LineBasicMaterial` into a `THREE.LineSegments` mesh.

**As a dirty, *very* dirty hack**, open the *Qgis2three.js* file that was created in your export directory and replace the `Q3D.PointLayer` function with this:

```
/*
Q3D.PointLayer --> Q3D.VectorLayer
*/
Q3D.PointLayer = function () {
  Q3D.VectorLayer.call(this);
  this.type = Q3D.LayerType.Point;
};

Q3D.PointLayer.prototype = Object.create(Q3D.VectorLayer.prototype);
Q3D.PointLayer.prototype.constructor = Q3D.PointLayer;

Q3D.PointLayer.prototype.loadJSONObject = function (jsonObject, scene) {
  Q3D.VectorLayer.prototype.loadJSONObject.call(this, jsonObject, scene);
};

Q3D.PointLayer.prototype.build = function (features) {
  var objType = this.properties.objType;
  if (objType == "Icon") { this.buildIcons(features); return; }
  if (objType == "JSON model" || objType == "COLLADA model") { this.buildModels(features); return; }

  var deg2rad = Math.PI / 180, rx = 90 * deg2rad;
  var setSR, unitGeom;
  // ### add new var to the function scope ###
  var edgeGeom;                                     

  if (objType == "Sphere") {
    setSR = function (mesh, geom) {
      mesh.scale.set(geom.r, geom.r, geom.r);
    };
    unitGeom = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1, 32, 32);
  }
  else if (objType == "Box") {
    setSR = function (mesh, geom) {
      mesh.scale.set(geom.w, geom.h, geom.d);
      mesh.rotation.x = rx;
    };
    unitGeom = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1);

    // ### add the 'THREE.EdgesGeometry' and pass it the 'unitGeom' ###
    edgeGeom = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(unitGeom);

  }
  else if (objType == "Disk") {
    var xAxis = Q3D.uv.i, zAxis = Q3D.uv.k;
    var sz = (this.ns === undefined || this.ns == false) ? this.sceneData.zExaggeration : 1;
    setSR = function (mesh, geom) {
      mesh.scale.set(geom.r, 1, geom.r * sz);
      mesh.rotateOnWorldAxis(xAxis, (90 - geom.d) * deg2rad);
      mesh.rotateOnWorldAxis(zAxis, -geom.dd * deg2rad);
    };BoxBufferGeometry
    unitGeom = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(1, 1, 0.0001, 32);
  }
  else {  // Cylinder or Cone
    setSR = function (mesh, geom) {
      mesh.scale.set(geom.r, geom.h, geom.r);
      mesh.rotation.x = rx;
    };
    unitGeom = (objType == "Cylinder") ? new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1, 32) : new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(0, 1, 1, 32);
  }

  // iteration for features
  var materials = this.materials;
  var f, geom, z_addend, i, l, mesh, pt;
  for (var fidx = 0, flen = features.length; fidx < flen; fidx++) {
    f = features[fidx];
    geom = f.geom;
    z_addend = (geom.h) ? geom.h / 2 : 0;
    for (i = 0, l = geom.pts.length; i < l; i++) {

      //### pass in 'edgeGeom' instead of 'unitGeom' ###
      mesh = new THREE.LineSegments(edgeGeom, materials.mtl(f.mtl));

      setSR(mesh, geom);

      pt = geom.pts[i];
      mesh.position.set(pt[0], pt[1], pt[2] + z_addend);
      //mesh.userData.featureId = fid;
      mesh.userData.properties = f.prop;

      this.addObject(mesh);
    }
  }
};
```

where I simply added/changed three lines, as denoted by the comments in the code.

**It's likely the code will break for other cases/with other export settings, but with simple boxes you should see the building outlines.**

Note the completely different meaning of *geometry* in this context compared to GIS.

Comment: btw. as I've just seen you also had an issue opened on the GitHub repository; this is not a bug or an issue by itself. the `wireframe` is primarily no design element, but a feature used for e.g. debugging. since it is realized with line primitives, any color added to the material is rendered on the lines (even textures will be applied to the lines). getting outlines in *Three.js* is a matter of geometry/material and needs to be handled/implemented by the application.